# Saving Excel File is changing the file access to read only

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, winforms

I'm trying to save the excel file, when an checkbox is being clicked. Here is the code that I have for it:

```
Private Sub CheckBox_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged

    'MsgBox(CType(sender, CheckBox).Name)

    Dim objExcel, objWorkbook, fileLocation

    fileLocation = "C:\Users\batman\Desktop\test3"

    objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open _
        (fileLocation)

    Dim strArray() As String
    strArray = CType(sender, CheckBox).Name.Split(",")


    objWorkbook.WorkSheets(CInt(strArray(0))).Activate()
    objExcel.Cells(CInt(strArray(1)), 3).Value = "From Windows Form"


    objWorkbook.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    objWorkbook.SaveAs(fileLocation)
    objWorkbook.Close(SaveChanges:=False)

End Sub
```

When I click the desired checkbox, I can see the excel value is being updated. But the file `test3` access is now got changed to `Read-Only` mode. So the next time the same click handler is failing with exception saying:

```
Cannot save read-only file system: test3.xlsx
```

Where I'm making the mistake? I'm using Microsoft excel 2007.

Comment: Is the XLSX file properties read only or are your permissions to Batman's desktop readonly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are double dotting the properties and calling `Close` is not closing the first Excel application. If you look in Task Manager, you will probably see it running.

The solution is to not double dot properties or methods and to use `Marshal.ReleaseCOMObject(...)`, then your workbook should close cleanly.